# Only Show Messages with RoomID in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am trying to create FireBase chat with separate rooms and only display messages from that room. How can I only show messages with `roomid = somenumber` (currently set to 4)

Data might look like this:

[image]

This is the code following the firebase documentation.

```
<body>

<!-- CHAT MARKUP -->
<div class="example-chat l-demo-container">
  <header>Firebase Chat Demo</header>

  <div class='example-chat-toolbar'>
    <label for="nameInput">Username:</label>
    <input type='text' id='nameInput' placeholder='enter a username...'>
  </div>

  <ul id='example-messages' class="example-chat-messages"></ul>

  <footer>
    <input type='text' id='messageInput'  placeholder='Type a message...'>
  </footer>
</div>

<!-- CHAT JAVACRIPT -->
<script>
  // CREATE A REFERENCE TO FIREBASE
  var messagesRef = new Firebase('https://blistering-fire-1740.firebaseio.com/');

  // REGISTER DOM ELEMENTS
  var messageField = $('#messageInput');
  var nameField = $('#nameInput');
  var messageList = $('#example-messages');

  // LISTEN FOR KEYPRESS EVENT
  messageField.keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      //FIELD VALUES
      var username = nameField.val();
      var message = messageField.val();

      //SAVE DATA TO FIREBASE AND EMPTY FIELD
      messagesRef.push({name:username, text:message, roomid:4});
      messageField.val('');
    }
  });

  // Add a callback that is triggered for each chat message.
  messagesRef.limitToLast(10).on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
    //GET DATA
    var data = snapshot.val();
    var username = data.name || "anonymous";
    var message = data.text;

    //CREATE ELEMENTS MESSAGE & SANITIZE TEXT
    var messageElement = $("<li>");
    var nameElement = $("<strong class='example-chat-username'></strong>")
    nameElement.text(username);
    messageElement.text(message).prepend(nameElement);

    //ADD MESSAGE
    messageList.append(messageElement)

    //SCROLL TO BOTTOM OF MESSAGE LIST
    messageList[0].scrollTop = messageList[0].scrollHeight;
  });
</script>
</body>
```

[firebase doc](https://www.firebase.com/tutorial/#session/zwyd6xjfydw)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dan's answer will work, but it means that you're downloading all the chat messages. User's on smaller data plans will appreciate it if you don't download data that is not needed:

```
var roomMessages = messagesRef.orderByChild('roomid').equalTo(4);
roomMessages.limitToLast(10).on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
    //GET DATA
    var data = snapshot.val();
```

You'll need an index on `roomid`, as described [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/indexing-data.html).

Answer (score 1):

Simply filter out messages that don't belong to that room, when you add them to the DOM.

```
// Add a callback that is triggered for each chat message.
messagesRef.limitToLast(10).on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
  var data = snapshot.val();

  // break out of the function early if this message does not
  // belong in this room.
  if(data.roomId !== 4) return;

  var username = data.name || "anonymous";
  var message = data.text;

  // ...
});
```

You probably don't want to hardcode the roomID into your code. It would make sense to store the current room ID in a variable somewhere, then check against that instead.

```
  var currentRoomId = getRoomId(); // get from URL, or from Firebase
  // ...
  if(data.roomId !== currentRoomId) return;
```